Parsing Power BI Dash w Selenium/BeautifulSoup
I can't seem to parse a dynamic Power BI Dash after scrolling it.
The code came from a similar question tasks with scraping the same Power BI Dash. My only interest is scraping the lower table of this Dash. The code I slightly adjusted came from this github account.
I see the table being scraped horizontally and vertically, but then when I go to parse it using selenium and BeautifulSoup as two options, the output is only a fraction of the table. I've adjusted time.sleep argument to give more time but it didn't do anything.
Any help would be much appreciated.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiNzA0MGM4NGMtN2E5Ny00NDU3LWJiNzMtOWFlMGIyMDczZjg2IiwidCI6IjM4MmZiOGIwLTRkYzMtNDEwNy04MGJkLTM1OTViMjQzMmZhZSIsImMiOjZ9&pageName=ReportSection")

# wait for the dashboard to load
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'transform.bringToFront')))

# scroll
scrolls = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.scroll-bar-part-bar')
h_scroll = scrolls[2]
v_scroll = scrolls[3]

# find the desired 2nd table
table = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.tableExContainer')[1]

flag = True
while flag:
    try:
        # Perform vertical scrolling
        action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
        action_chains.move_to_element(v_scroll).click_and_hold().move_by_offset(0, 100).release().perform()
    except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
        flag = False
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# Transition to BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")
rows = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'role': 'row'})
rows_data = []

# Initialize rows_data to collect data from all rows
for row in rows[1:]:
    cells = row.find_all('div', attrs={'role': 'gridcell'})
    cell_texts = [cell.get_text() for cell in cells[1:]]  # Skip the first cell
    rows_data.append(cell_texts)

headers = table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[role='columnheader']")

h = []
h.pop[0]
for header in headers:
    h.append(header.text.strip())

# Capture headers again after scrolling
column_headers = table.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[role="columnheader"]')
# Initialize a list to hold the text of each column header
header_texts = []
for header in column_headers:
    # Extract and append the text from each header
    header_texts.append(header.text)

I only perform vertically scroll first to solve 1 problem at a time. h prints out the headers that are visible before. scrolling.
 
>>> h
['Row Selection', 'Job Name', 'State', 'Licensed, Registered or Certified by State', 'Education Requirement', 'Amount of Training Required (In Hours)', 'Amount of Experience Required', 'Professional Exam', 'Required Time of License Renewal (In Years)', 'Continuing Education Requirement', 'Additional Required Exams', 'Cost of Initial Licensure (In Dollars)', 'Cost of License Renewal (In Dollars)', 'Reciprocity or Endorsement', 'Good Moral Character Requirement']
>>> 

But the rows data only seem to be 41 rows long.
 print(len(rows_data))
41

